# android kotlin '1.6.21 breaks navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin

my project was using kotin '1.5.10' when I updated to 1.6.21 , the navigation component breaks
what happens?

Screen A is navigation to B

```
    findNavController().navigate((
    CarFragmentDirections.actionCarFragmentToCarDetailsFragment(
        selectUrl, viewModel.CarParameters()))
```

B is working is opened
but when I press the phone back button,
Fragment A recreates everything, all text files lose data,
however, ViewModel is no anymore connected to the view. , live data is stopped updating the view. the B view is empty and click listeners do not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using view-binding solve my issue